How to add another column in counting the value using createQueryBuilder?
This code works properly when I query the details of the user in counting the devices connecting to each user.
 $em = $this->getEntityManager();
 $query = 'SELECT u.id, u.email, COALESCE(c, 0) devices FROM user u left join (select user_id, count(user_id) c from user_device where permission_level = 3 group by user_id) ud on u.id = ud.user_id';

 $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
 $result = $statement->executeQuery()->fetchAllAssociative();
 dd($result);

the output of this query is



id
email
devices




1
test@gmail.com
5


2
test2@gmail.com
1



I would to know if there is another way to achieve the same result using
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

I tried to implement it but it cannot read the COALESCE functionality.
In this scenario, I have a table user



id
email




1
test@gmail.com


2
test2@gmail.com



I have table user_device



user
device




1
12


1
13


1
15


1
14


2
12


1
16



